# Reindex products manully

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

I am new to magento .I want to reindex the products manually but I don't know where model and controller files path. please help me for reindexing the products.

Comment: manually means SSH or what ?

Comment: All the tings is here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12645/21339

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the server using the SSH credentials provided to you by our Support Team.
Navigate to your Magento installation:

`/home/demo/demosite.com/html/`

After accessing the Magento directory, navigate to the shell directory:

`cd shell`

To view the current status of the Magento indexer, enter:

`php indexer.php --status`

To issue a reindex of all categories, enter:

`php indexer.php --reindexall`

To see a list of specific categories for reindexing, enter:

`php indexer.php info`

.

also You can try install https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin system->indexmangaement-> select all-> and reindex